# Was there any public reaction inside Poland when Poles abroad were asked to report ‘Anti-Polish’ statements?

Tags: poland

According to [this article](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2018-02-15/poles-abroad-asked-to-report-anti-polish-statements) Poland's senate leader has appealed to Poles living abroad to report to the authorities any statements deemed to hurt "Poland's good name":

> Warsaw, Poland (AP) -- Poland's senate leader has appealed to Poles
>   living abroad to report to the authorities any statements deemed to
>   hurt "Poland's good name" — part of a wider campaign by the government
>   to defend the country against what it calls historical untruth and
>   slander.

This is confirmed by [this article](https://www.politico.eu/article/poles-abroad-told-to-flag-anti-polish-comments-report/):

> Poles living abroad have been instructed to report comments made by
>   compatriots that could be “harmful” to Poland’s reputation, according
>   to a report by German public broadcaster NDR.

This was eclipsed by the law that penalizes publicly and falsely attributing the crimes of Nazi Germany to the Polish nation, but in my country (Romania) had some echo because it reminded to many of the period before the fall of the communism, when a little whisper in the wrong direction could put you in jail due to "Security" paying attention to any "thought-crime".

I am wondering if there was any public reaction inside Poland to this advice.

**Question:** Was there any public reaction inside Poland when Poles abroad were asked to report ‘Anti-Polish’ statements?

Comment: I think your question is flawed, because lack of reaction cannot be proven.

Answer (score 3):

> Poles living abroad have been instructed to report comments **made by compatriots** that could be “harmful” to Poland’s reputation, according to a report by German public broadcaster NDR.

I've looked up and read few articles and while I've found few describing situation similar to what's quoted **minus the bold part**, I couldn't find anything about "made by compatriots":

- [Rather neutral](https://wiadomosci.wp.pl/ndr-polonia-ma-zglaszac-antypolskie-wypowiedzi-list-od-marszalka-6220477307275393a), dully reports the fact that a memo appeared that calls to report badmouthing Poland. Same [here](http://www.dw.com/pl/ndr-polonia-ma-zg%C5%82asza%C4%87-antypolskie-wypowiedzi/a-42593422) and [here](https://wiadomosci.onet.pl/swiat/niemcy-krytyka-apelu-o-zglaszanie-antypolskich-opinii-godne-ubolewania/1mmdmmg)
- [Opposition](https://koduj24.pl/polonia-ma-zglaszac-antypolskie-wypowiedzi/) focuses on quoting ambassador: "zwyczajne obowiązki przedstawicielstwa dyplomatycznego lub konsularnego" - "usual duties of diplomatic or consular representation" and mocks ambassador asking regular citizens to do his job.
- [vulgarly anti-government](https://www.salon24.pl/u/kuba-rozpruwacz/845020,nabor-kapusiow-dla-rezimowej-wladzy):  "Wg niemieckich mediów „Polska wzywa do donosicielstwa”." - "According to German media, „Poland calls to snitch”". Still, nothing about snitching on each other, rants about snitching in general.

Peculiar thing is that even Polish news refer to the [NDR article](https://www.tagesschau.de/ausland/polen-315.html). User @Nebr was kind enough to provide its summary:

> The German NDR article states that Poles living abroad should report anti-Polish statements to Polish officials. It does not say that this is confined to comments from compatriots. On the contrary, a letter is quoted saying: "Please, document any anti-Polish statements, depictions and opinions that could harm us, and react upon this. Inform our embassies, consulates, and honorary consulates about any defamation that is able to influence the good reputation of Poland."

Therefore it's safe to assume that **"made by compatriots" is a mistranslation or overinterpretation, existing in an article Zach Sayer of Politico,**  but not in reports closer to the source.

Taking above into account, it's unsurprising that the whole thing went rather low-key, focusing on Germans criticizing the memo rather than the memo itself. It appears that relationship with Germany is the biggest concern here. Some articles mention calls to Poles abroad to be "ambassadors of Poland" made by Marshall of Senate earlier this month. Which is something they were doing anyway, since "polish death camps" are often found by Poles living abroad and reported to the nearest consulate.

Comment: The German NDR article states that Poles living abroad should report anti-Polish statements to Polish officials. It does not say that this is confined to comments from compatriots. On the contrary, a letter is quoted saying: "Please, document any anti-Polish statements, depictions and opinions that could harm us, and react upon this. Inform our embassies, consulates, and honorary consulates about any defamation that is able to influence the good reputation of Poland."